# easybill API python, extract from json in pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I need to download recipes from easybill via api.
so far so good. I came down to a data frame looking like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 70 entries, 0 to 69
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   document_date  70 non-null     object
 1   items          70 non-null     object
 2   number         70 non-null     object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 1.8+ KB
None
```

the column items contains a json string with N lines.

```
[{'booking_account': None, 'cost_price_charge': None, 'cost_price_charge_type': 'AMOUNT', 'cost_price_net': 0, 'cost_price_total': 0, 'description': 'item1', 'discount': 25, 'discount_type': 'PERCENT', 'export_cost_1': None, 'export_cost_2': None, 'id': 998150606, 'item_type': 'PRODUCT', 'number': '03', 'position': 1, 'position_id': 31136986, 'quantity': 6, 'quantity_str': '6', 'serial_number': None, 'serial_number_id': None, 'single_price_gross': 2299, 'single_price_net': 1931.9328, 'total_price_gross': 10345.5001, 'total_price_net': 8693.6976, 'total_vat': 1651.8025, 'type': 'POSITION', 'unit': None, 'vat_percent': 19}, 
{'booking_account': None, 'cost_price_charge': None, 'cost_price_charge_type': 'AMOUNT', 'cost_price_net': 0, 'cost_price_total': 0, 'description': 'item', 'discount': 25, 'discount_type': 'PERCENT', 'export_cost_1': None, 'export_cost_2': None, 'id': 998150611, 'item_type': 'PRODUCT', 'number': '04', 'position': 2, 'position_id': 31136991, 'quantity': 18, 'quantity_str': '18', 'serial_number': None, 'serial_number_id': None, 'single_price_gross': 3499, 'single_price_net': 2940.3361, 'total_price_gross': 47236.4994, 'total_price_net': 39694.5374, 'total_vat': 7541.9621, 'type': 'POSITION', 'unit': None, 'vat_percent': 19}]
```

I would like to have a new DF containing the following columns:
document_date, number, description.

i have tried this:

```
data = data[['document_date','items','number']] #1

dict_df = data.to_dict(orient="records")
data = data(dict_df, record_path="items", meta=["document_date", "number"])
data = data[[ 'document_date', 'number', 'description']]
```

but it throws an error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

does anybody have an idea?

thanks!

**** UPDATE ****
copy and paste issue. working solution:

```
data = data[['document_date','items','number']] #1

dict_df = data.to_dict(orient="records")
data = json_normalize(dict_df, record_path="items", meta=["document_date", "number"])

data = data[[ 'document_date', 'number', 'description']]
```

Comment: I think that the error comes because you first set `data = data[['document_date','items','number']]` as a `DataFrame`, and then you use `data(dict_df, record_path="items", meta=["document_date", "number"])` like calling a function?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing concepts.  `to_dict()` is a `pandas` method not a `list` method.  If you just want a subset of columns where you already have a data frame use `loc[]`

A number of the columns you noted are not in sample data you provided.

```
d = [{'booking_account': None, 'cost_price_charge': None, 'cost_price_charge_type': 'AMOUNT', 'cost_price_net': 0, 'cost_price_total': 0, 'description': 'item1', 'discount': 25, 'discount_type': 'PERCENT', 'export_cost_1': None, 'export_cost_2': None, 'id': 998150606, 'item_type': 'PRODUCT', 'number': '03', 'position': 1, 'position_id': 31136986, 'quantity': 6, 'quantity_str': '6', 'serial_number': None, 'serial_number_id': None, 'single_price_gross': 2299, 'single_price_net': 1931.9328, 'total_price_gross': 10345.5001, 'total_price_net': 8693.6976, 'total_vat': 1651.8025, 'type': 'POSITION', 'unit': None, 'vat_percent': 19}, 
{'booking_account': None, 'cost_price_charge': None, 'cost_price_charge_type': 'AMOUNT', 'cost_price_net': 0, 'cost_price_total': 0, 'description': 'item', 'discount': 25, 'discount_type': 'PERCENT', 'export_cost_1': None, 'export_cost_2': None, 'id': 998150611, 'item_type': 'PRODUCT', 'number': '04', 'position': 2, 'position_id': 31136991, 'quantity': 18, 'quantity_str': '18', 'serial_number': None, 'serial_number_id': None, 'single_price_gross': 3499, 'single_price_net': 2940.3361, 'total_price_gross': 47236.4994, 'total_price_net': 39694.5374, 'total_vat': 7541.9621, 'type': 'POSITION', 'unit': None, 'vat_percent': 19}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
data = ['document_date','items','number']
data = [c for c in data if c in list(df.columns)]

df.loc[:,data]
```